# printf() and format specifier linking

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

i understand quite well as to how printf() and format specifier works

**NOTE:- I am using Turbo c/c++ compiler and ye si know gcc,g++,etc are way better but the problem remains same**

code:-

```
void main()
{
 clrscr();
 printf("%d %d %d");
 getch();
}
```

**output:- 0 344 0**

now,

code:-

```
void main()
{
 clrscr();
 printf("%f %f %f");
 getch();
}
```

**output:- printf : floating point formats not linked
Abnormal program termination.**

now , also note that i have tried this on around 200 systems.

**Question:-I believe that those format specifier numbers that are displayed on the output are not garbage as for every system same result is obtained and their is some link between printf() function and format specifier through file handling or pointer. So can anyone now finally tell what it might be?**

note:-result may vary from IDE to IDE but is same for a compiler on every system as i have tried this on codeblocks IDE also.

Comment: "I believe that those format specifier numbers that are displayed on the output are not garbage" - you're invoking *undefined behavior*. Belief is the only thing you have going for you, because everything else has already gone out the window.

Comment: This is undefined behavior.  You're using format specifiers that require additional arguments, but you're failing to provide them.  So you're getting unspecified garbage.  You're also declaring `main` incorrectly.  It returns an `int`, and needs to be declared as such.

Comment: like i said i have tested this on a large no. of systems so yes i believe cause the result on all systems for both compiler was same also turbo c compiler is actually the borland c compiler created by  Dennis Ritchie and edited by the folks at borland and according to ANSI C main can have void return type.

Comment: Are you sure your Turbo C compiler supports floating points? Or maybe a special option is required to turn this support on? Read this http://c-faq.com/fp/fpnotlinked.html

Comment: This question is utterly uninteresting and should be closed.  If you *really* want to see what your random stack accesses are doing on *your* platform, look at the assembly code and figure it out.  It's a tedious waste of time, but not at all hard.  So do it and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks guys that helps a lot but what I am originally trying to determine is that  why values on random stack access is same for all systems or like when the compiler is loaded in the memory these values are automatically inserted into the stack.

Comment: Reopened as per *NeoR*'s comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037395/printf-and-format-specifier-linking/38037472?noredirect=1#comment63516101_38037395

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So can anyone now finally tell what it might be?

From the [C11 Standard (draft) for the library function `fprintf()`](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1):

> **7.21.6.1/2**
>
> [...]
>
> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.

After code has invoked undefined behaviour *anything* could happen.

Comment: I understand that and though the draft says that shouldn't the result vary on different systems then i could understand the undefined behaviour also i have understanding of compiler design so i am currently viewing it as an undefined automata in the compiler design.

Answer (score 0):

> output:- printf : floating point formats not linked Abnormal program termination.

Turbo C and *some* compilers do not link in the floating point support unless floating point code is detected in user code.  `"%f %f %f"` needs FP support to work, yet the compiler does not recognize it at *compile* time.  Instead the program fails at *run* time.

Add FP code and get rid of other mis-use of `printf()`;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  clrscr();
  double a = sqrt(2.0):
  printf("%f %f %f\n",a,a,a);
  getch();
}
```